# Is there a way to automatically create a variable in java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    String fileLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String dataPath = fileLocation + File.separator + "predators.txt";

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(dataPath);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    input.useDelimiter(":");
    String predatorsName, latinName, weight, speed, stealth, risk, killer, interestingFact;

    for (int i = 0; input.hasNext(); i++) {
        predatorsName = input.next();
        latinName = input.next();
        weight = input.next();
        speed = input.next();
        stealth = input.next();
        risk = input.next();
        killer = input.next();
        interestingFact = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(weight);
    }          
}
```

Hi I have a program here that scans a file will multiple data on animals and then assigns each words/numbers to the according string using input.next(). Right now when I print the weight all the animals weight gets printed in the output. I want to know if there is a way to... say for e.g print the weight of the animal on the third line? thank you

Comment: Create a `Predator` class. As you read lines from the file, instantiate instances of your `Predator` class. Add those instances to a `List<Predator>`. Call `list.get(2)` and get the weight (and then print it).

Comment: This line is wrong: `input.useDelimiter(":");` It should be this: `input = input.useDelimiter(":");`

Comment: @NickODell There's no difference.

Comment: @NickODell No, it's not wrong.  According to the Javadoc, `useDelimiter` just returns `this`.  Assigning `input` to itself won't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why It Doesn't Work**

The reason why it is printing out all the weights is because in the loop you have this:

```
for (int i = 0; input.hasNext(); i++) {
    ...
    weight = input.next();
    ...
    System.out.println(weight);
}
```

What this means is that in each iteration of the loop, it will first store the weight, and then display it. As such, every weight will thus be printed out in the output.

**Solution**

I would create a `Predator` class, and instead of displaying the weights in the loop (as per your current implementation), we will use it to populate the data into a list of Predators. We will only display them later after this is done.

Creation of the Predator class:

```
class Predator{
    String predatorName;
    String latinName;
    String weight;
    ..

    //add your getters and setters as well
}
```

Then using it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    List<Predator> predatorList = new ArrayList();
    String fileLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String dataPath = fileLocation + File.separator + "predators.txt";

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(dataPath);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

    input.useDelimiter(":");

    List<Predator> predatorList = new ArrayList();
    Predator predator = new Predator();             

    for (int i = 0; input.hasNext(); i++) {
        predator.setPredatorName(input.next());
        predator.setLatinName(input.next()));
        ...
        predatorList.add(predator);
    }
}
```

And finally retrieving the different predators in the list is as simple as:

```
Predator myPredator = predatorList.get(0); //which returns you the first predator in the list.
System.out.println(myPredator.getWeight()); // this will only print out the weight of the first predator
```

In the above example I am re-using the same `predator` variable in the loop. You could of course create a new `Predator` instance every iteration of the loop if you wanted to, but that means you're essentially creating a new object per iteration.